# In the UK, does redeployment always mean continuous employment?

Tags: employment

Suppose someone is made redundant from an "open-ended" job on 31 Dec 2021. The employer, who is in the UK, has a redeployment policy that places an employee at risk of redundancy in a 'redeployment pool' during the notice period, which is 3 months, so that the employee is given a prior consideration for any relevant jobs that might become available during the notice period. However, in this case, the full notice period was not served by the employer. Hence, the employer allows the employee to be in the redeployment pool for 3 months beyond the date of redundancy, i.e. till 31 March 2022.

In February 2022, i.e. after he is made redundant but within the allowed redeployment period, the employee does find a suitable alternative role for himself with this same employer. And surely enough, the employer hires this employee back at the same salary level (and the same seniority level) that he used to work earlier. No issues there.

**The question is:** should this be considered continuous employment (i.e. without break of service during January-February 2022)?

Comment: Was the employee actually dismissed, did they stop working? Did they receive a redundancy payment?

Comment: @Lag The employee was given an honorary, i.e. unpaid, position during Jan/Feb 2022, during which he did do some work for this employer in a sort of voluntary manner. The employee did receive a redundancy payment at the end of Dec 2021.